# Force https on all pages except for 1 page with a specific value in a Query String Parameter

Tags: mod-rewrite, redirect, https

I have already searched this site but my workaround does not work.

Basically, I need all pages to have https turned on except for 1 page that has a url like this:

```
domain.com/begin/index.php?pageid=130&usertype=1&building=2
```

If the page has the Querystring parameter **`pageid=130`** I do not want https turned on.

My `.htaccess` file looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

#HTTPS OFF on pageid 130
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)pageid=(130)($|&)
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

#FORCE HTTPS ON ALL PAGES except for pageid 130
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)pageid=(130)($|&)
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Answer (score 0):

LOL! Small mistake but hard to spot: you still redirect to `https` ;). Just remove the '`s`'.

Otherwise may redirect for sure and stop the rewrite process = Last = `L`.

```
RewriteEngine On

# HTTPS Off on pageid 130
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)pageid=130($|&)
# (!) Remove the "s":
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,NC,L]

# Force HTTPS on all pages but the one QS 'pageid=130'
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} Off
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)pageid=130($|&)
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,NC,L]
```